# doctrine prefix in by doctrine-module

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

How can I map all classes from my database with doctrine-module in console? I am doing the following:

```
./vendor/doctrine/doctrine-module/bin/doctrine-module orm:convert-mapping --namespace="Application\Entity\\" --force  --from-database annotation ./module/Application/src/
```

My tables have prefix name like tbl_user, tbl_cad, tbl_products. When it is generated classes - they have names like TblProducts, TblUser etc... 
I want to create names like Products, User, etc... removing "tbl_"/"Tbl" prefix.
How could I do this?